# Custom Command that invokes 2nd Editable Popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I have an MVC 5 app that I'm using a Telerik Grid with.  All is good so far.

Except I am trying to have a Custom Command that invokes an Editable Popup, just like the Edit Command does when set to `GridEditMode.Popup`.  This would display a subset of data from my model that the Grid is bound to.

I've seen this demo here --> http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-command
on Custom Commands but I'm wondering how I turn that into an editable screen.

I realize this is a little vague but I'm not sure what, more specific, question to ask at this point?  If I had to try I guess I'm wondering if there's an alternative to building the whole Edit screen by hand, in html, and embedding it on that page, like the demo shows.

I have the following Model. I'm trying to get the child, ModelB, in it's own popup.

```
ModelA 
Guid          ID
string        Name
IList<ModelB> Roles

ModelB
Guid          ID
Guid          ModelA_ID
string        Role
```

Comment: Do you want to edit a row from the grid or do you have some other data that you want to edit in a custom window?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add my model to my question, thanks.

Comment: There's no need to add your model. I just didn't understand if your question is about grid editing or not?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to edit the children in another grid inside the popup editor (inside the [MVC editor template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates)). The child grid needs to be bound to its own controller/actions which take the parent ID (`modelA_ID`) as an input parameter.

The main grid may look like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelA>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(e => e.Name);
    columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit();
            command.Destroy();
        });
})
.ToolBar(tools => tools.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable
    .Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.PopUp)
    .TemplateName("MyTemplate"))
.Pageable().Sortable().Filterable()
.DataSource(source => source.Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(e => e.ID))
    .Read(read => read.Action("Read_ModelA", "MyController"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Update_ModelA", "MyController"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("Create_ModelA", "MyController"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy_ModelA", "MyController"))))
```

and in the editor template (`MyTemplate.cshtml`) you might have:

```
@model ModelA
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModelA_ID)
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelB>()
.Name("childGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(o => o.Role);
    columns.Command(command =>
    {
        command.Edit();
        command.Destroy();
    });
})
.ToolBar(tools => tools.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable
      .Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InLine))
.Pageable().Sortable().Filterable()
.DataSource(source => source.Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(e => e.ID))
    .Read(read => read.Action("Read_ModelB", "MyController").Data("getCurrentParentId"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("Create_ModelB", "MyController").Data("getCurrentParentId"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Update_ModelB", "MyController"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy_ModelB", "MyController")))
.ToClientTemplate()
)
```

and the javascript function `getCurrentParentId` looks like this:

```
function getCurrentParentId() {
    return {
        modelA_ID: $('#ModelA_ID').val()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll give this a try though won't this just create a Grid in the Edit Popup that I already have?  If so I need it to be in a separate popup, that's the weirdness of my requirement.  They want to see all the Data together but have 2 different workflows for Editing.  Make sense?

Comment: Can't you use [hierarchical grids](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy)?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so unless I can have a popup for each.  I'll have to look around as I'm not even sure that's possible...

Comment: I'm sure you can have popup editing for each. Just make sure to set the parent id in the edit event of the child. Unfortunately, if you need to make some custom UI that is not similar to the demos, you're going to need to write a lot of hard-to-maintain javascript.

Comment: Okay, cool.  I'll definitely give it a try based on your answer.  It won't be exactly what "they" are asking for but pretty dang close so here's hoping!

Comment: After playing around with this and just thinking about it some more I don't think this is a solution to my stated issue.  Still willing to admit I'm wrong but it seems like there is no way to perform Editing on `ModelA` with this method.  It will display it in the grid but when I click the Edit button the popup will use the stated template which displays `ModelB` in another grid.  What I need is 2 different buttons, on the main Grid, one for editing `ModelA` and one for editing `ModelA.MobelB<>`.  It's a weird requirement, I know!

Comment: It's okay. There's no urge to accept my answer. Take a look at [this blog post](https://ggacura.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/6/) which might give you ideas on how to implement your requirements.